# Irreducible representation of $S_n$: contained in tensor powers of the standard representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

Let $S_n$ be the permutation group and $V = \operatorname{Fun}(X,\mathbb{k})$ functions from $X=\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ to some field $\mathbb{k}$. How can I prove that every irreducible representation of $S_n$ occurs in $V^{\otimes m}$ for integer $m$ large enough?

This is a standard fact when $n!\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{k}$.

Comment: This is a standard fact that holds for any faithful representation of any finite group.

Comment: how about using schur functions here?

Comment: @lambda, is it true for any faithful representation *in any characteristic*?  I don't know that it isn't, but I thought that there might be some problems in case the characteristic  of $\mathbb k$ divides $n!$.

Comment: Use the orthogonality relation and show that the inner product of any irreducible character of $S_n$ with character of $V^{\otimes m}$ does not vanish for large $m$.

Comment: Not to keep beating the same (possibly wrong, to mix metaphors) horse, but, @DianbinBao, isn't that a characteristic-$0$ argument?

Comment: @LSpice, yes, it only works for characteristic 0 case.

Comment: @LSpice I believe that if the word "occurs" is interpreted correctly for the non-semisimple setting (i.e. a composition factor, not necessarily a summand) then it is true all characteristics, but I guess I did glance past the fact that the OP wanted this for arbitrary fields.

Comment: See https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141710-X/S0002-9939-1962-0141710-X.pdf

Comment: @LSpice, yes, it works for characteristic 0 case. As the OP mentioned $n!\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{K}$. The inner product makes sense and the argument still works by Schur's lemma.

Comment: Does "occurs" mean as a subfactor, as a subrepresentation, as a summand, ... ?

Comment: @DianbinBao, re [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368031/irreducible-representation-of-s-n-contained-in-tensor-powers-of-the-standard#comment928277_368031), I think that the post mentions that this is a known fact when $n! \ne 0$, but does not actually assume that $n! \ne 0$.

Comment: @Dianbin, the OP mentioned that the result is standard in this case, it is *not* an assumption of the question that $\mathbb{K}$ is of zero characteristic.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, [wow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368031/irreducible-representation-of-s-n-contained-in-tensor-powers-of-the-standard#comment928275_368031), yet another illustration of the beauty that's to be found in (that other) Steinberg's works!  As @‍lambda and @‍DavidESpeyer mention, the sense of 'constituent' there is 'subquotient'.  Is there an easy example of a representation that can't be realised as a subobject of a tensor power $V^{\otimes m}$?

Comment: (Just to have the name here, @BenjaminSteinberg's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368031/irreducible-representation-of-s-n-contained-in-tensor-powers-of-the-standard#comment928275_368031) is to [Robert Steinberg - Complete sets of representations of algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141710-X).)

Comment: @LSpice, for finite groups every irreducible appears as subrepresentation of the regular representation because the group algebra is Frobenius.  R. Steinberg proves the regular representation appears inside of a direct sum of the tensor powers and so you get them as subobjects. But Steinberg also proves his theorem for finite semigroups and in that case you do not get them all as subobjects.

Comment: @LSpice for instance of you take the monoid of all maps on n letters then the trivial representation is a quotient of the natural representation on $\mathbb C^n$ but not a subobject of any Tensor power.

Comment: There is a nice proof in Alperin's book Local Representation Theory that works in any characteristic and for any faithful module: see Theorem 1 on page 45.

Answer (score 13):

Turning my comment into an answer, Robert Steinberg proved in [Complete sets of representations of algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141710-X/) that if you have a faithful representation of a finite semigroup $S$, then every irreducible representation of $S$ appears as a composition factor of a tensor power of that representation.  In fact, he shows that the semigroup algebra $KS$ acts faithfully on the direct sum of the tensor powers, which is a stronger statement since finite semigroups are not usually completely reducible.  My favorite proof of this is Passman’s variant of a proof of Rieffel in [Elementary bialgebra properties of group rings and enveloping rings:  An introduction to Hopf algebras](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Epassman/balgebra.pdf).

If $G$ is a finite group, then $KG$ is a Frobenius algebra and so every irreducible representation is a subrepresentation of the regular representation.  Thus in the case of a finite group, every irreducible representation will be a subobject of a tensor power.

For semigroups, this is not true.  There are many examples.  The easiest is the monoid $T_n$ of all maps on $n$ letters.  For $n\geq 2$, the natural representation on $\mathbb C^n$ is faithful and has the trivial representation as a quotient but not as a subrepresentation.  The same remains true after taking tensor powers.

Comment: It seems to me that the regular representation of $S_n$ occurs, specifically, in $V^{\otimes n}$ where $V$ is functions on an $n$-element set,  as the subspace of functions on the $n$th power of an $n$ element set which vanish on all $n$-tuples that are not permutations. So we can take $m=n$ here.

Comment: That is true in this case since that module is just the action of the group on functions n to n.  The general case can require n the size of S.

Answer (score 11):

Benjamin Steinberg answered the question, but I wanted to unwind his idea into an explicit formula.

Let $V$ be the representation with basis $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$, where a permutation $\sigma$ acts by sending $e_i$ to $e_{\sigma(i)}$.

Let $W$ be an irreducible representation of $S_n$.

Fix a linear form $l$ on $W$. We can map $W$ to $V^{\otimes n}$ by sending $w \in W$ to
$$f(w) = \sum_{ \sigma \in S_n}  l ( \sigma^{-1} (w))\cdot  e_{\sigma (1) }\otimes e_{\sigma(2)} \otimes \dotsm\otimes  e_{ \sigma(n) }.$$

Then we have
\begin{align*}
\sigma' (f(w)) & {}= \sum_{ \sigma \in S_n}  l ( \sigma^{-1} (w))\cdot  \sigma'( e_{\sigma (1) }\otimes e_{\sigma(2)} \otimes \dotsm e_{ \sigma(n) } ) \\
& {}= \sum_{ \sigma \in S_n}  l ( \sigma^{-1} (w))\cdot e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(1))} \otimes e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(2))}  \otimes  \dotsm \otimes  e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(n))} \\
& {}= \sum_{ \sigma \in S_n}  l ( (\sigma' \circ \sigma)^{-1}( \sigma'(w)))\cdot e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(1))} \otimes e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(2))}  \otimes  \dotsm \otimes  e_{ \sigma'(\sigma(n))} \\
& {}=  \sum_{ \sigma \in S_n}  l ( \sigma^{-1} (\sigma' (w) ))\cdot  e_{\sigma (1) }\otimes e_{\sigma(2)} \otimes \dotsm\otimes  e_{ \sigma(n) } = f(\sigma' (w))
\end{align*}
using the change of variables $\sigma \mapsto \sigma' \circ \sigma$ in the last line. So $f$ is a homomorphism, and because $W$ is irreducible, and $f$ is nontrivial (as long as $l$ is a nontrivial linear form, since all the terms in the sum give different basis vectors in the tensor product), this map is the inclusion of a subrepresentation, as desired.

One can get embeddings into $V^{\otimes m}$ for higher values of $m$ by just putting repetitions in the sequence of basis vectors being tensored, or for $n-1$ by removing the last term, but one can't go lower than $n-1$, because of the sign representation (except maybe in characteristic $2$, I guess).

Comment: Sorry for the silly question—why does the sign representation prevent going lower than $n - 1$?

Comment: @LSpice Suppose there is a copy of the sign representation in the tensor product. Take a generator (or the generator, since it's unique up to scaling). Write it in a basis of tensors of basis elements. Find one tensor of basis elements which has a nonzero coefficient. Since only $n-2$ basis elements can appear, two don't. Swap those and derive a contradiction.